# Sending a MSAL token to backend using Axios

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, axios, azure-ad-msal

I am trying to send user id which is being previously decoded from JWT token (together with data inputted by user). Unfortunately, at the moment when I try to send it, I am getting an exception in the backend saying that data in the request array is null:

> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.
> ---> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Approver1lvl', table 'Requests'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.

Judging by the console log info I see in the browser, the token is decoded correctly. So, that makes me think that there is a mistake in the customInstance.post part.

Here is my code:

```
export default function NewRequest() {
  const [userData, setUserData] = useState({
    firstName: "",
    surname: "",
    co: "",
    homeAddress: "",
    postCode: "",
    city: "",
    country: "",
    phonePrefix: "",
    phoneNumber: "",
    email: "",
    approver1lvl: "",
    employeeId: "",
    userId: ""
  });

 const handleSubmit = () => {
    var token = localStorage.getItem("msal.idtoken");
    var jwt = jwt_decode(token);
    const {
      firstName,
      surname,
      co,
      homeAddress,
      postCode,
      city,
      country,
      phonePrefix,
      phoneNumber,
      email,
      approver1lvl,
      employeeId,
      date,
    } = userData;

    const user = {
      firstName,
      surname,
      co,
      homeAddress,
      postCode,
      city,
      country,
      phonePrefix,
      phoneNumber,
      email,
      approver1lvl,
      employeeId,
      birth,
    };

   
    customInstance.post("Request",  {user, userId: jwt.oid}).then((response) => {});
  };
```

Does anyone knows how to fix that?

EDIT: Screenshot of an error in the browser: [image]

EDIT2: I have successfully send a POST using swagger, which looked like this:
[image]

Comment: Could you show us request log on your browser (F12, then see on network tab) to check how the request is sent ?

Comment: @LahEzcen I have added the screenshot.

Comment: perfect, the userId is sent correctly by axios. Now you will need to check on back side if you receive it as expected before trying to persist to database.

Comment: The problem is that it's not being send correctly, I am getting a 500 error in the console. Worth noting is that I want to store all data (request array and user id) in the same table. I think the problem lies in how my axios post is structured, but nothing I have tried so far works.

Comment: Could you use Postman instead of Axios ? do you have an example of a working request payload ? like this you will be sure if the issue is caused by Axios

Comment: @LahEzcen I have tested it in Swagger (I have updated my question with a screenshot).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see in the Swagger that userId is in the same level as email, phone ..., I think it should work like this:

```
export default function NewRequest() {
  const [userData, setUserData] = useState({
    firstName: "",
    surname: "",
    co: "",
    homeAddress: "",
    postCode: "",
    city: "",
    country: "",
    phonePrefix: "",
    phoneNumber: "",
    email: "",
    approver1lvl: "",
    employeeId: "",
    userId: ""
  });

 const handleSubmit = () => {
    var token = localStorage.getItem("msal.idtoken");
    var jwt = jwt_decode(token);
    const {
      firstName,
      surname,
      co,
      homeAddress,
      postCode,
      city,
      country,
      phonePrefix,
      phoneNumber,
      email,
      approver1lvl,
      employeeId,
      date,
    } = userData;

    const user = {
      firstName,
      surname,
      co,
      homeAddress,
      postCode,
      city,
      country,
      phonePrefix,
      phoneNumber,
      email,
      approver1lvl,
      employeeId,
      birth,
    };

   
    customInstance.post("Request",  {...user, userId: jwt.oid}).then((response) => {});
  };
```

Comment: Your suggestion has worked! Thank you very much!

Comment: My pleasure! We are here to help each other :)